# Service Records for http

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, http, dns-server, srv-record

Is it recommended to use SRV / service records resource records for http?

Are there any significant advantages or drawbacks for using them in http?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are protocols that require `SRV` records in order to determine where the service is located, like SIP. HTTP is not among those protocols. As there's no browser that would first check for `SRV` records, you wouldn't accomplish anything by adding them.